# I am trying to run a war file in jboss using resteasy services but not able to do so

Tags: java, maven, jboss, resteasy

I am trying to run a rest easy web services on my jboss eap 6.0 server my jboss server is up and running but when I am trying to copy my war file in deployment folder of jboss it is throughing an ModuleClassLoader exception....please help me finding the solution for this problem.....

**this is my web.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>Demo-RestEasyWebServices</display-name>



<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>



<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/rest</param-value>
</context-param>

 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>

</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**this is my pom.xml-**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">


 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


 <groupId>Demo-RestEasyWebServices</groupId>


<artifactId>Demo-RestEasyWebServices</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


 <packaging>war</packaging>



<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.6.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
        <systemPath>${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>

            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <version>5</version>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass></mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <!-- <modules> <webModule> <groupId>com.macys.smt</groupId> <artifactId>APM-HBaseService</artifactId> 
                    <contextRoot>/apmservice</contextRoot> </webModule> </modules> -->
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>


</build>
```

**java Program**

```
package com.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/message")
public class RestServicesMessage {

@GET
@Path("/{param}")
public Response displaymessage(@PathParam("param") String msg)
{
    String message= "Restfull Web Services Message" + msg;

    return Response.status(200).entity(message).build();

}
```

}

**the exception**

```
10:58:05,801 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/Demo-RestEasyWebServices-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 9) JBWEB000285: Error configuring application listener of class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap from [Module "deployment.Demo-RestEasyWebServices-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.newInstance(WebInjectionContainer.java:78) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3294) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3780) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:163) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:61) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:96) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved by removing the listner class in the web.xml file.....and also because my ambari server is using the port 8080 so I changed the port of ambari and my resteasy webservices is working fine on 8080 port for jboss.